# unable to pull data from hidden HTML tags

Tags: html, excel, vba

Below HTML code act as tooltip info, appears on mouse hover over link.
using .getelementbyclassname method, i'm not able to fetch the value "Story & Experience" from page.
I guess, until the tooltip is visible on load, the HTML code is unavailable for extraction. How to make it visible or extract the data ?

I'm using EXCEL VBA to do this actions.

```
 <div id="ext-comp-1115" class="x-tip rich-tooltip" style="position: absolute; z-index: 25000; visibility: hidden; padding: 3px 0px 5px; width: 323px; left: 131px; top: 168px; display: none;">
<div class="ellipsis">Type: <span class="rich-tooltip-item">Story &amp; Experience</span></div></div></div>
```

VBA code:

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
IE.navigate "https://swym.3ds.com/#post:16884"
IE.Visible = True
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:016"))
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set doc = IE.document
Dim dd As Variant
dd = doc.getElementsByClassName("ellipsis").tags("span") 
MsgBox dd
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you add the portion of vba code you are using for this?

Comment: Edit your question and add it there. With the information you have provided, it's not clear what is the problem.

Comment: Sorry, just today i created the account, Edit was hard to find !

Comment: The link in your `IE.Navigate` points to a page where username & password need to be entered. This page doesn't contain a `<div class="ellipsis">` Have you taken this into account and/or is the above URL just a placeholder for the real one?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike.
I've already logged in and kept a IE window open throughout, so it is not necessary to login all time. This is a one piece of code to fetch the tool tip alone. Login and navigate to the post url, use Inspect on chrome or Firefox over tool tip of the first occuring letter "SwYmers' Hall" in the webpage. you can find the `<div class = "ellipsis">` when inspected the text of tooltip i.e. Type: Story & Experience. I've pasted this tag by copying code from webpage.

Answer (score 0):

doc.getElementsByClassName("ellipsis").tags("span") returns an object rather than a string value. I believe you're looking for the innerText attribute of the tag, so either...

```
'Set dd equal to the "span" tag object
Set dd = doc.getElementsByClassName("ellipsis").tags("span")
MsgBox dd.innerText
```

or

```
'Assign the "span" tag object's innerText string value to the dd variable
dd = doc.getElementsByClassName("ellipsis").tags("span").innerText
MsgBox dd
```